# Can't add Office Interop Refs (Powerpoint specifically) to C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, ms-office, powerpoint

**Problem:**

Can't add the Microsoft.Office.Interop.* refs to a c# project (.NET 4 Client Profile). I used to be able to compile on a different machine using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint.

**What I've tried:**

Installed the [Office 2010 PIA](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508). I was able to get the Microsoft.Office.Core to load just fine from the PIA installation. And in fact the PIA readme says it includes the interops for all the office products including Powerpoint. But when I look in programs/Microsoft Office/Office14/ I don't see any DLLs that look like the rest of the interops (Though I'm not familiar with what should be here anyway).

Also tried using .NET 3.5 project to see if the interops only work with that build target.

**Environment:** 
Win 7, VS C# Express 2010, .NET 4, Deployment Server has Office products installed

Here's what I see in the refs dialog:
[image]

And you can see that Core loaded fine:

[image]

Comment: @HansPassant I see nothing remotely office related in the .NET tab. I have PPT on the production server so that's no problem. I even uninstalled and re-installed the PIA. No dice. This is a pretty new system, too, so less potential for conflicts/too many versions of VS installed.